# tblastn not providing full alignment even on exact-matching sequences

Tags: blast

I am using tblastn to search a polypeptide seq against transcripts.  One of those transcripts contains the residues for that exact polypeptide once translated, yet BLAST only gets 88% of it rather than it being full length.

Here's the peptide:

```
>Syntaxin
MTKDRLAALKAAQSDDDDNDDVAVTVDSSGFMEEFFEQVDEIREMIDKIASNVDEVKKKHSAILSAPQTDD
KMKEELEELMSEIKKNANKVRAKLKVIEQNIEQEEHTNKSSADLRIRKTQHATLSRKFVEVMNDYNACQID
YRERCKGRIKRQLAITGKTTTNEELEDMIESGNPAIFTQGIIMETQQANETLADIEARHNDIMKLETSIRD
LHDMFMDMAMLVESQGEMIDRIEYNVEQAVDYIETAKMDTKKAVKYQSKARRKKIMILVCLAILIIILVGV
IGGTLG
```

And the [transcript](https://gist.github.com/jorvis/b1543e3284d80f6e7226505fcb4f5bbb).

Here's the first-frame translation of the transcript which contains the exact polypeptide above:

frame +1

```
> - 669
PATRNITIVSIYDYH*NNDLKCVFTE*MEILNRIWILLNSHSP*AQRLHAI**MTKDRLAALKAAQSDDDD
NDDVAVTVDSSGFMEEFFEQVDEIREMIDKIASNVDEVKKKHSAILSAPQTDDKMKEELEELMSEIKKNAN
KVRAKLKVIEQNIEQEEHTNKSSADLRIRKTQHATLSRKFVEVMNDYNACQIDYRERCKGRIKRQLAITGK
TTTNEELEDMIESGNPAIFTQGIIMETQQANETLADIEARHNDIMKLETSIRDLHDMFMDMAMLVESQGEM
IDRIEYNVEQAVDYIETAKMDTKKAVKYQSKARRKKIMILVCLAILIIILVGVIGGTLG***PSSLPLVYS
LIQLFYAACTTAASNIWTHHNRNSYYYNSNSNSNSNCYSNYFSNYYSNRKHYYYYHYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
YYYYYYDYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYCYYYYYYYYYHFHYYYHHYYYHYYYYHYYYHYHHHHHYHYHYHYHHH
HHYHYHYHYHYHYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYCYYYYYYTFSLVISLYGSSEM*MRLLVLSLYTFYGLF
YPLQQKGSFFF*SLQQTGTGFYNFFSYCQLHNLSIPSPSYFF*EWVFSFLKKHLIEFFCFLILLKFVLSFS
PIISLIISVCRKKISRIFYTIYLKMS**NHYLLF
```

Yet when I do a local tblastn (using the modern blast+) or use NCBI's pairwise blast tool it doesn't return a full-length match.

Why does it leave off the last 12% of the sequence match?

Here's the alignment:

[image: screenshot of the alignment]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because by default, blast masks [low complexity regions](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?CMD=Web&PAGE_TYPE=BlastDocs&DOC_TYPE=FAQ#LCR). With the online [blast2seqs tool](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PROGRAM=tblastn&PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&BLAST_SPEC=blast2seq&LINK_LOC=blasttab&LAST_PAGE=blastn&BLAST_INIT=blast2seq), you can disable this by clicking on the "Algorithm options" button:

[image: Screenshot of the NCBI blast2seqs page showing the relevant option]

And then deselect the "Low complexity regions" filter:

[image: Screenshot of the NCBI blast2seqs page showing the relevant option]

This will let you align the entire sequence as expected:

```
Alignment statistics for match #1
Score   Expect  Method  Identities  Positives   Gaps
Frame
588 bits(1516)  0.0 Compositional matrix adjust.    290/290(100%)   290/290(100%)   0/290(0%)
+1
Query  1     MTKDRLAALKAAQSDDDDNDDVAVTVDSSGFMEEFFEQVDEIREMIDKIASNVDEVKKKH  60
             MTKDRLAALKAAQSDDDDNDDVAVTVDSSGFMEEFFEQVDEIREMIDKIASNVDEVKKKH
Sbjct  154   MTKDRLAALKAAQSDDDDNDDVAVTVDSSGFMEEFFEQVDEIREMIDKIASNVDEVKKKH  333

Query  61    SAILSAPQTDDKMKEELEELMSEIKKNANKVRAKLKVIEQNIEQEEHTNKSSADLRIRKT  120
             SAILSAPQTDDKMKEELEELMSEIKKNANKVRAKLKVIEQNIEQEEHTNKSSADLRIRKT
Sbjct  334   SAILSAPQTDDKMKEELEELMSEIKKNANKVRAKLKVIEQNIEQEEHTNKSSADLRIRKT  513

Query  121   QHATLSRKFVEVMNDYNACQIDYRERCKGRIKRQLAITGKTTTNEELEDMIESGNPAIFT  180
             QHATLSRKFVEVMNDYNACQIDYRERCKGRIKRQLAITGKTTTNEELEDMIESGNPAIFT
Sbjct  514   QHATLSRKFVEVMNDYNACQIDYRERCKGRIKRQLAITGKTTTNEELEDMIESGNPAIFT  693

Query  181   QGIIMETQQANETLADIEARHNDIMKLETSIRDLHDMFMDMAMLVESQGEMIDRIEYNVE  240
             QGIIMETQQANETLADIEARHNDIMKLETSIRDLHDMFMDMAMLVESQGEMIDRIEYNVE
Sbjct  694   QGIIMETQQANETLADIEARHNDIMKLETSIRDLHDMFMDMAMLVESQGEMIDRIEYNVE  873

Query  241   QAVDYIETAKMDTKKAVKYQSKARRKKIMILVCLAILIIILVGVIGGTLG  290
             QAVDYIETAKMDTKKAVKYQSKARRKKIMILVCLAILIIILVGVIGGTLG
Sbjct  874   QAVDYIETAKMDTKKAVKYQSKARRKKIMILVCLAILIIILVGVIGGTLG  1023
```

This is the part of your transcript sequence that was masked:

```
acgctaggctgaccctcctccctccctctagtctactccttaatacaattgttctacgccgcgtgcacc
```

I am guessing it is the repeated `ccct` nucleotides that resulted in the sequence being masked, but I am not sure.